# Looping through a word inside a script itself and changing it

Tags: javascript

I wonder if it is possible to replace all instances of a word in javascript. Say for instance I want to replace all instances of "function" with fn. I know doing so renders my function useless but this is just to give an example.

So my trouble is, **1.** how do I access text within the script itself? Script traversing, similar to how we travel the node tree.

**2.** I assume such action comes with security risks, is that right?

Say you have a script like this:

```
var x = function () {

    function y () {
       // ...
    }

}
```

Comment: Why was this downvoted?

Comment: It's not possible for a script to traverse itself

Comment: I guess what you are describing is called `minification`. There are tools to do that, but as @JonathanBrooks said, its not possible to traverse self.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by using `eval`

Look at this:

```
myScript = "myFunc = function foo() {console.log(9999)}";
eval(myScript);
```

Now you can run the function through `myFunc()`

It gets interesting here.

Change the name `foo` in your `myScript` to `bar` and the number to `0000`

```
myScript = myScript.replace("foo", "bar");
myScript = myScript.replace("9999", "0000");
eval(myScript);
myFunc();
```

The function `bar` executes and prints `0000`

There are lot of other ways you can do this. You can use JQuery getScript, for example, and be little creative to go a long way in this direction.

---

UPDATE

Taking the answer bit further...

There is a specific reason why I wanted to use the variable `myFunc`

To understand, run the following snippet

```
myScript = "function foo() {console.log(9999)}";
eval(myScript);
myScript = "function bar() {console.log(0000)}";
eval(myScript);

foo();
bar();
```

Now guess the reason why I used `myFunc`

Comment: By the way, read some of my comments in the answer below. Nice, im new eval and never really touched it since I heared its the devil in code, but hey its awesome. Any security concerns and how to avoid them in your solution?

Comment: The script itself is not functional though since it is a string. Could you explain how this works?

Comment: Please see the documentation for 'eval'. This is a working example.

Comment: I avoid 3rd party libraries. Love doing things in scratch. So hey, so the first answer I recieved has the issue that there is no guarantee that the script updates itself when I change something. Is this the case with the eval technique as well? I mean the browser caches the script as far as im concerned

Comment: Ya I will check out the documentation. Of course, the examples work perfectly fine. I just want to know the pros and cons of doing this and I will accept your answer : )

Comment: Only the DOM changes in the first answer. It doesn't change the executable context. You can even delete the entire <script> tag in the DOM - but your functions work as how they are loaded.

Comment: Im aware of injection possibilities if eval is used. In this context, how would you rate the security?

Comment: I don't see a threat if you use your own scripts. It seems both JQuery and Angular uses evel. Try to understand how the dynamic scripts working in JS. You can go your journey safely if you know the road well.

Comment: Thank you for your advice and answer

Answer (score 0):

You can access a `script` element like any other element.  However, it will contain only one text node, which is the script itself.

You can do a replace on the text node like this:

```js
var x = function () {
  console.log('I still work!');
    function y () {
       // ...
    }

}

var script= document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
script.textContent= script.textContent.replace(/function/g, 'fn');
document.querySelector('pre').textContent= script.textContent.trim();
x(); //I still work!
```

```html
<pre></pre>
```

Note that changing the text note does *not* necessarily affect the functionality of the script.

Comment: Im telling you why im asking this. Im thinking of creating fallbacks for things like "let". So if let is not supported then I will replace all instances of let with var. It sounds crazy but this is what those kind of things could be useful for

Comment: Will the changing of the script inside the <script> tag change the executable script itself?

Comment: Do we have to use prepared statements or something like in PHP? I mean what are the security risks

Comment: Security risks may depend on the browser.  In Chrome using my example, `x()` was still defined after I changed the text content.  You could use this method to write a JavaScript parser, which could translate the code into another language.  (Although that would be quite a bit of work.)

Comment: It seems to be an issue with caching then. There must be some function though to refresh the cache or reset the entire thing without refreshing the page, so that could be solved then. I know about the traversal of dom elements but is it possible to traverse external js files and change text there?

Comment: This is only changing DOM. It has nothing to do with the execution. The original script will be in the executable memory and will not be changed this way.